# common mysql table in a server connect to different mysql Servers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a country table in server A and I want to have a reference it in different servers B, C and D.

How can I Join A with B, A with C and so on? Or Should I create a view of Country table in B,C and D?

Comment: Can u describe the country table and its change in data

Answer (score 1):

To acquire this on the database level you will need to setup replication, you can read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

Or use federated tables, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html).

Comment: I just read about federated table structure. Is there any other possible options ?

Comment: I do not know any other techniques.